# How do I fit the height of my website to a mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a mobile version of my pre-existing website. I added this to my code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

And along with CSS edits, I've done a good job. However, it's too tall for my site. Even though I set the device height, the user still has to scroll down to see the entire page. I want it to box itself in the device screen size. My heights are set to 100%, but that didn't work. I even tried "vh".

What can I do to override this and shrink the height to the exact screen size?

Comment: While possible this is probably a really bad idea. I solve this problem using jQuery for mobile devices as it let's you listen for the screen size change event.

Comment: jQuery mobile doesn't seem to work with ASP NET MVC 4.0.

Comment: You should probably tag your question as ASP then.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all references to height and only worry about width. Height is generally determined by the vertical size of the content. Users don't mind scrolling up/down, so height isn't usually that big of a deal, but they HATE scrolling left/right, so we generally only worry about width.

Comment: I agree.  Limiting the height the user can scroll is bad practice.  What happens if they are on a tiny device (Pocket Neo?) that has a ~320px high screen?

Comment: Hate to be picky, but this isn't actually answering the question. Remember that Stack Overflow is primarily for *future visitors having the same problem*. You should answer the OP's question anyway, but keep the bit about *this approach is bad because...*. Any future visitor would be disappointed, and remember that there *could be an edge case* where such a feature could be used.